# javascript mailto works in chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, undefined, mailto

I'm trying to build a simple webpage for our lab engineers so when they are sitting at their station they can open the web page shortcut from their desktop > select which lab they are in > select which kind of support they require > then click submit to open an email with all the selected information inserted > then hit send; which then sends an email request to those in the email list.

Everything works great in Chrome, but most of our engineers use IE by default, when I click the submit button in IE, it opens the email, but the To: and Subject: read "UNDEFINED". I am using IE10.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="silsupport.css">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<title>SILSupport</title>

<body>
<h1>SIL Support</h1>
<SCRIPT>
    function e_mail(e_add,subject1,body)
    {
        window.location="mailto:"+e_add+"?subject="+subject1+"&body="+body;
    }
</SCRIPT>
<form name="e_form" enctype="text/plain">
    <div id="para1">    
        <p>Please select which lab you are in: </p>                     
            <input name="subj" type="radio" value="Lab_1 Support" />Lab 1<br />
            <input name="subj" type="radio" value="Lab_2 Support" />Lab 2<br />
            <input name="subj" type="radio" value="Lab_3 Support" />Lab 3<br />
            <input name="subj" type="radio" value="Lab_4 Support" />Lab 4<br />
            <input name="subj" type="radio" value="Lab_5 Support" />Lab 5<br />
    </div>       

    <div id="para2">
        <p>Please select which support you require:</p>
            <input name="emadd" type="radio"  value="re@abc.com" />RE Support<br />
            <input name="emadd" type="radio"  value="admin@abc.com" />Admin Support<br />
            <input name="emadd" type="radio"  value="system@abc.com" />System Support<br />
            <input name="emadd" type="radio"  value="hwsw@abc.com" />H/W &amp; S/W Support<br />
            <input name="body"  type="hidden" value="I require support now!" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="Submit" Value="Submit" onClick="e_mail(this.form.emadd.value,this.form.subj.value,this.form.body.value)" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a dropdown as you should have

Comment: @mplungjan https://storify.com/lukew/drop-downs-are-the-ui-of-last-resort

Comment: @Pointy - the article is about mobile apps.

Comment: @mplungjan true but in my opinion everything's a mobile app now :) I just think it's an interesting viewpoint, and of course it's more of a design issue than a technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should have your own code to find the checked radio button:

```
function findChecked(radios) {
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length && !radios[i].checked; ++i);
    return radios[i] && radios[i].value;
}
```

That function expects a list, which is what you'll get from the by-name reference to the radio button groups. It looks for the checked button and returns its value.

Then:

```
<input type="button" id="Submit" Value="Submit"
  onClick="e_mail(findChecked(this.form.emadd),findChecked(this.form.subj),this.form.body.value)" />
```

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/metd2rcz/)

Comment: this code fixed my problem! It works in IE now! Sweet! Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know if I need to create a separate troubleshooting page for this, but is it possible to source a file for the radio button? So the single email address was just a test, I need to add multiple addresses with the possibility of changing them in the future, so I figure a simple text file with the list would be easiest to source. thoughts?

Comment: @user1904711 well it totally depends on what your server-side infrastructure looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is due to character encoding in your URL.
Change your code to this to escape characters such as spaces and the exclamation mark:

```
window.location="mailto:"+ encodeURIComponent(e_add) +"?subject="+ encodeURIComponent(subject1) +"&body="+ encodeURIComponent(body);
```

Comment: this code does the same thing my code does. produces "undefined" in To: and Subject:

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do since a single radio value may not be supported in IE
Also escape the space in the lab. Please note I changed the form name to id and the button to an actual submit

Lastly you can add  size="5" and ="4" to the dropdowns to show all options

[DEMO](http://plungjan.name/SO/mailtotest.html)

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("e_form").onsubmit=function() {
    var e_add = this.emadd.value,
        subject1=this.subj.value,
        body=this.body.value,
        loc="mailto:"+e_add+"?subject="+encodeURIComponent(subject1)+"&body="+body;

    window.location=loc;
    return false; // cancel submit
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="e_form" enctype="text/plain">
  <div id="para1">  
    <p>Please select which lab you are in: </p>            
    <select name="subj">
      <option value="Lab_1 Support">Lab 1</option>
      <option value="Lab_2 Support">Lab 2</option>
      <option value="Lab_3 Support">Lab 3</option>
      <option value="Lab_4 Support">Lab 4</option>
      <option value="Lab_5 Support">Lab 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>       
  <div id="para2">
    <p>Please select which support you require:</p>
    <select name="emadd">
      <option value="re@abc.com">RE Support</option>
      <option value="admin@abc.com">Admin Support</option>
      <option value="system@abc.com">System Support</option>
      <option value="hwsw@abc.com">H/W &amp; S/W Support</option>
    </select>
    <input name="body"  type="hidden" value="I require support now!" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" Value="Send"  />
</form>
```

Comment: so this code does not work in my IE browser. it doesn't even open the email client. please be mindful i'm on a corporate LAN so would it be possible there are settings being turned off that may be impacting the code? on MY code when I open the page in IE I am prompted with 'IE restricted this web page from running scripts or Active X controls, Allow block content?" in which I click "allow". Just an FYI.

Comment: Try this: http://plungjan.name/SO/mailtotest.html - on my corporate PC I get a  warning, but it works if I allow it

Comment: sweet. that works, as well! would you know if it is possible to source a file with a radio button. the single email was just part of the development, but I need to add multiple email addresses that I can easily add/remove in the future. I'm assuming a simple text file with the list of emails would suffice. Do I need to start a new troubleshooting page for this question? Oh, I just noticed you did away with the radio buttons...haha

Comment: Yes, makes more sense to me. If you want you can have the addresses in a JS file